# Generate all stacks to a function

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse allows to get all references to a function. I'd like to go further and know if anyone knows of a tool or script that would do this recursively ie from a function it would produce the list of different possible function stacks to access to it.

I am looking for this to make sure all the impacts of a change are captured in the spaghetti old legacy code I am looking at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try eclipse's [Call Hierarchy](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-call-hierarchy.htm).
It's `CTRL`-`ALT`-`H` on Windows, `CTRL`-`OPTION`-`H` on OS X.

(Hotkeys for eclipse 3.x, I have yet to use eclipse 4)

Comment: Yep, thanks this is what I was looking for, i did not get my search key words right to land on it

Answer (score 1):

Its called the [Call Hierarchy](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-call-hierarchy.htm) and you can open it with Ctrl+Alt+H

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/19-list-shortcuts-key-eclipse.html